# Algorithms for counting identical characters in the same position between two strings

Tags: python, optimization

Which of the two is a more optimal and/or more pythonic code?
Functions return the number of positions in string 1 that contain the same character in the corresponding position in string 2   :

```
def compare(s1, s2):
    count = 0
    for i in s1:
        if i == s2[s1.index(i)]:
            count += 1
    print(count)

def compare2(s1, s2):
    count = 0
    for i in range(0, len(s1)):
        if s1[i] == s2[i]:
            count += 1
    print(count)
```

Comment: def compare(s1, s2):
 count = 0
 for i in s1:
  if i == s2[s1.index(i)]:
   count += 1
 print(count)

Comment: That's the 1st function that went into the question in the post for some reason

Comment: [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) — [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) — [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)

Comment: `count = sum(1 for a, b in zip(s1, s2) if a == b)`

Comment: Iterate values instead of using index: `sum(i==j for i,j in zip(s1,s2))`

Comment: just convert each list into a set and use bitwise `&` operator comparison `set(s1) & set(s2)` considering you only have small to moderate lists

Comment: @Nik391, ...if only adding the values to the set, vs the `enumerate()` results, that wouldn't require like positions, so it would be a different result.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly in term of performance, the first *compare()* is quadratic because it has an O(n) *index()* operation inside an O(n) for-loop.  The second *compare2()* is much better because is uses O(1) random access indexing with `i`.

That said, @CharlesDuffy pointed out correctness issues which need to be addressed first.

For long strings where function call overhead isn't important, consider this alternative which should run very fast:

```
>>> a = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> b = 'a---e---i-----o-----u---y-'
>>> sum(map(str.__eq__, a, b))
6
```

In Python 2, add this optimization for improved cache efficiency:

```
>>> from itertools import imap          # iterator version of map()
>>> sum(imap(str.__eq__, a, b))
6
```

Answer (score -2):

The second one is more optimal as your not calling a function ( c1.index() ) unnecessarily.

Comment: More to the point, the first one is *wrong*; if a character is present twice, `index()` will only ever return the first location for it, so the code using index won't validate correct location in the second string for any but the first instance of a given character.

Comment: Yes. I  missed that!